# 'Build' error when nesting form attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, build, nested-attributes

I'm encountering an error when trying to create a new nested form.

I have 3 models:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :hires
 has_many :books, through: :hires
end

class Hire < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :books
 belongs_to :children
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hires
  has_many :children, through: :hires
  belongs_to :genres
end
```

I'm trying to set up a view which allows children to 'hire' 2 books.

The view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@hire) do |f| %>

 <%= hires_form.label :child %><br>
 <%= hires_form.select(:child, Child.all.collect {|a| [a.nickname, a.id]}) -%>

  <%= f.fields_for :books do |books_form| %>

   <%= books_form.label :book %><br>
   <%= books_form.select(:book, Book.all.collect {|a| [a.Title, a.id]}) -%>
   <%= books_form.label :book %><br>
   <%= books_form.select(:book, Book.all.collect {|a| [a.Title, a.id]}) -%>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class HiresController < ApplicationController

...    

 def new
     @hire = Hire.new
     2.times { @hire.books.build }
 end

 def create
    @hire = Hire.new(hire_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hire.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hire, notice: 'Hire was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hire }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @hire.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 ...    

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_hire
      @hire = Hire.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def hire_params
      params.require(:hire).permit(:book, :child, books_attributes: [:id, :book, :child, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

I'm getting the error:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

I feel this is something obvious that i'm missing but any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 belongs_to :books
 belongs_to :children
```

You need to singularize these.

```
 belongs_to :book
 belongs_to :child
```

Also see section 2.4 of the rails guides as a reference *"The has_many :through Association"*:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

*Keep in mind that you are using a belongs_to on the Hire object.*

Notice the methods that are added when using the belongs_to association:

```
association(force_reload = false)
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {})
```

So you should be able to use the method build_book on the Hire object (eg. @hire.build_book of @hire.build_child).

The methods added by the has_many association are:

```
collection(force_reload = false)
collection<<(object, ...)
collection.delete(object, ...)
collection.destroy(object, ...)
collection=(objects)
collection_singular_ids
collection_singular_ids=(ids)
collection.clear
collection.empty?
collection.size
collection.find(...)
collection.where(...)
collection.exists?(...)
collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)
collection.create(attributes = {})
collection.create!(attributes = {})
```

Which can be used on your Book and Child objects. For example: `@book.childeren.build or @child.books.build.`

*For reference see the rails guides section 4.2 and 4.3 'Methods Added by ..':*
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for this. Made this change: `belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :child` and kept the controller code as `2.times { @hire.books.build }` still getting the error `undefined method 'books' for #<Hire:0x007fe74987b148>`. When i change the controller code to `2.times { @hire.book.build }` i get the error `undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, but a Hire will only have one Book and one Child object. If you want to access books you'll need to do this from a child object `@child.books.build`. If you need to do this from the Hire object then use the `@hire.build_book`.

For reference see the rails guides sub section '4.1.1 Methods Added by belongs_to'.